# emberjs action context is bound to the child component view instead of the component

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to pass an action up from a child component with `sendAction`. My action executes on the parent component as expected, however, `this` refers to the context of the child's `view` object instead.

See below for the components and component templates:

Parent component Template

```
// templates/components/parent.hbs  
<div class="parent">

    {{child name="Stewie" select="selectChild"}}
    {{child name="Molly" select="selectChild"}}

</div>
{{yield}}
```

Child component Template

```
// templates/components/child.hbs    
<div class="child" {{action "handleAction" on="click"}}>

  name: {{name}}

</div>
{{yield}}
```

Child component

```
  // components/child.js  
  import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      selected: false,

      actions: {
        handleAction: function() {
          this.set('selected', !this.get('selected'));

          this.sendAction('select', this);
        }
      }
    });
```

Parent component

```
  // components/parent.js
  import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.Component.extend({

    selectedChildren: [],

    actions: {

      selectChild: function(child) {
             // oops! this is bound to the child's view isntead of this parent component

        var selectedChildren = this.get('selectedChildren');
          // undefined

        selectedChildren.pushObject(child);
        // oops! cannot call pushObject of undefined
      }
    }
  });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
handleAction: function() {
  // ...
  this.sendAction('select', this.get('name')); // this.get('name') instead of this
}
```

In your code `this.sendAction('select', this)` means passing Component Object to parent component, so next behavior looks strange.

Comment: You're right. passing "this" to my action payload should have been the first sign of a code smell.